# easiest way to figure out what waiver() is doing?

Tags: ggplot2

If one looks at the (e.g.) `ggplot2::scale_y_continuous`, the default value of many of the arguments is set to `waiver()`, e.g. for `breaks`:

> ‘waiver()’ for the default breaks computed by the
> transformation object

How does one figure out/look at how these defaults are computed? Let's say I want to find the breaks for `scale_y_log10()`. `?scales::log10_trans` doesn't say anything about computation of breakpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can hunt down the answer for the general case as follows.

First generate and store a ggproto scale object:

```r
scale_object <- ggplot2::scale_y_continuous()
```

If we examine this object's members, the `breaks` by default is simply a `waiver` object, as pointed out in the question.

```r
scale_object$breaks
#> list()
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "waiver"
```

But a scale object has to return a value for its breaks when interrogated during the ggplot build process. It does this via its `get_breaks` member function:

```r
scale_object$get_breaks
#> <ggproto method>
#>   <Wrapper function>
#>     function (...) 
#> get_breaks(..., self = self)
#> 
#>   <Inner function (f)>
#>     function (self, limits = self$get_limits()) 
#> {
#>     if (self$is_empty()) {
#>         return(numeric())
#>     }
#>     domain <- suppressWarnings(self$trans$transform(self$trans$domain))
#>     domain <- sort(domain)
#>     if (length(domain) == 2) {
#>         limits <- oob_squish(limits, domain)
#>     }
#>     limits <- self$trans$inverse(limits)
#>     if (is.null(self$breaks)) {
#>         return(NULL)
#>     }
#>     if (identical(self$breaks, NA)) {
#>         cli::cli_abort("Invalid {.arg breaks} specification. Use {.val NULL}, not {.val NA}")
#>     }
#>     if (zero_range(as.numeric(limits))) {
#>         breaks <- limits[1]
#>     }
#>     else if (is.waive(self$breaks)) {
#>         if (!is.null(self$n.breaks) && trans_support_nbreaks(self$trans)) {
#>             breaks <- self$trans$breaks(limits, self$n.breaks)
#>         }
#>         else {
#>             if (!is.null(self$n.breaks)) {
#>                 cli::cli_warn("Ignoring {.arg n.breaks}. Use a {.cls trans} object that supports setting number of breaks")
#>             }
#>             breaks <- self$trans$breaks(limits)
#>         }
#>     }
#>     else if (is.function(self$breaks)) {
#>         breaks <- self$breaks(limits)
#>     }
#>     else {
#>         breaks <- self$breaks
#>     }
#>     breaks <- self$trans$transform(breaks)
#>     breaks <- censor(breaks, self$trans$transform(limits), only.finite = FALSE)
#>     breaks
#> }
```

If we follow the conditional logic through, we see that in the case of `breaks` being a `waiver`, it is the `breaks` member function of the scale's `trans` member that is used. A `trans` object is a transformer class as defined via the `scales` package, and all position scale objects have one. By default this is the identity transform as returned by `scales::identity_trans()`

Therefore, the *general* solution, if we want to find the function that generates the breaks when `breaks` is `waiver`, is:

```
scale_object$trans$breaks
#> function (x, n = n_default) 
#> {
#>     x <- x[is.finite(x)]
#>     if (length(x) == 0) {
#>         return(numeric())
#>     }
#>     rng <- range(x)
#>     labeling::extended(rng[1], rng[2], n, ...)
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x0000017801fb08d0>
#> <environment: 0x0000017801fb3b78>
```

In this case, the `trans` object is the identity transform, so the function is the same as

```r
 scales::identity_trans()$breaks
#> function (x, n = n_default) 
#> {
#>     x <- x[is.finite(x)]
#>     if (length(x) == 0) {
#>         return(numeric())
#>     }
#>     rng <- range(x)
#>     labeling::extended(rng[1], rng[2], n, ...)
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x00000177aba49c88>
#> <environment: 0x00000177aba49010>
```

Of course, if you pass your own breaks or your own transformer, these will be used instead.

<sup>Created on 2023-08-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think `log10_trans()$breaks` might do it, which is the same as `?log_breaks`. Not sure how to figure this out in general, though ...